# PL/SQL Union statement common variables need to define?

Tags: plsql

```
  SELECT JOBNO,
         SUBJOBNO,
         SUM (IPCST) IPCST,
         SUM (VAD) VAD,
         SUM (WSTVAD) WSTVAD,
         SUM (PRQTY) PRQTY,
         SUM (ACC) ACC,
         SUM (SGVAD) SGVAD
    FROM (  SELECT jobno,
                   subjobno,
                   SUM (ipcost) IPCST,
                   0 VAD,
                   0 WSTVAD,
                   0 PRQTY,
                   0 ACC,
                   0 SGVAD
              FROM stt_prdtl
             WHERE jobno = 123 AND wktype = 100
          GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
          UNION
            SELECT jobno,
                   subjobno,
                   0 IPCST,
                   SUM (vadncost) VAD,
                   0 WSTVAD,
                   0 PRQTY,
                   0 ACC,
                   0 SGVAD
              FROM stt_prdtl
             WHERE jobno = 123
          GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
          UNION
            SELECT jobno,
                   subjobno,
                   0 IPCST,
                   0 VAD,
                   SUM (wstvadncost) WSTVAD,
                   0 PRQTY,
                   0 ACC,
                   0 SGVAD
              FROM stt_prdtl
             WHERE jobno = 123
          GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
          UNION
            SELECT jobno,
                   subjobno,
                   0 IPCST,
                   0 VAD,
                   0 WSTVAD,
                   SUM (prdqty) PRQTY,
                   0 ACC,
                   0 SGVAD
              FROM stt_prdtl
             WHERE jobno = 123 AND wktype = 500
          GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
          UNION
            SELECT jobno,
                   subjob,
                   0 IPCST,
                   0 VAD,
                   0 WSTVAD,
                   0 PRQTY,
                   SUM (acc_cost) ACC,
                   0 SGVAD
              FROM stt_prhdr
             WHERE jobno = 123 AND status = 'C'
          GROUP BY jobno, subjob
          UNION
            SELECT jobno,
                   subjobno,
                   0 IPCST,
                   0 VAD,
                   0 WSTVAD,
                   0 PRQTY,
                   0 ACC,
                   SUM (sgvadcost) SGVAD
              FROM stt_prdtl
             WHERE jobno = 123 AND wktype = 500
          GROUP BY jobno, subjobno)
GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
ORDER BY subjobno;
```

Any one can you help me how to define the Jobno number commonly instead of typing each line. I need to define that variable commonly at the head of the code from there itself the script need to call.

I expect the result from any one?

Comment: Please use {} symbol to format your query. It is not readable.Have you tried using jobno=123 from outside?

Comment: you need to use `WITH` expression here.

Comment: Outside I have define by Declare method but it couldn't work.  Actually I don't know the Oracle. I am learner while implementing in my company. so please correct my code & put the full code. The Jobno I want to declare outside this script at one time from there each table it should be pick. Please correct it & put the full script. thanks

Comment: @senthilkumar What exactly are you trying to achieve by introducing variable into your code? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Instead of typing Jobno in each line I want to define commonly at top of the script from there program should call automatic. Thanks for your replying. I am expecting your answer how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
   jobno_var number;  // or jobno_var table.column%type;
BEGIN
      // Now you can reference variable jobno_var anywhere in your code below
     SELECT JOBNO,
         SUBJOBNO,
         SUM (IPCST) IPCST,
        ...
         GROUP BY jobno, subjobno)
    GROUP BY jobno, subjobno
    ORDER BY subjobno;
END;
```

Comment: Not very good example of the code. At least you have to show how to use a variable, in the `INTO` clause for example.

Comment: @Dmitry Question is how to define variable in PL/SQL to reference it. I do address that concern in my answer. Are you suggesting to write comprehensive tutorial for each question?